# Unexpected values when printing addresses

Tags: c, pointers

This is my program. The output is given below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n = 3, *pt;
    pt = &n;
    printf("\n%d", pt);
    printf("\n%d", &n);
    printf("\n%d", &pt);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-9705676
-9705676
-9705672
```

But I think the third number should be same as first two? 
Please someone explain me why it is not so?

Comment: Printing addresses with `%d` is like confusing metric and imperial units. Rockets have gone "boom" because of this.

Comment: Why newline before contents? Newline after contents is very much cleaner. `printf("%d\n", value);`

Comment: Now I will remember form next time. Thankyou.

Answer (score 13):

It's all [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you are using wrong format specifiers to print pointers.

Use`%p` to print pointers and cast them to `void*`.

```
printf("\n%p",(void*) pt);
printf("\n%p",(void*) &n);
printf("\n%p",(void*) &pt);
```

The C standard requires that the argument corresponding to format specifie `%p` be of type `void*`.

**C11, 7.21.6, says:**

> p The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
>   implementation-defined manner.

Typically, a `T *` (any object pointer) can be implicitly converted to `void *` without an explicit cast (E.g. in assignments). But `printf()` is a variadic function and there's no such conversion happens here. So the casts are required.

> But I think the third number should be same as first two?

No. In the third you are printing the address of the pointer itself. Whereas in the first two, you are printing the address of `n`.

To illustrate this:

```
             +------+      
       n --> |      |  
      0x1000 |  3   |  n is stored at address 0x1000
             |      |
             +------+

             +------+      
      pt --> |      |  
      0x2000 |0x1000|  pt stores the address of n. 
             |      |  But the address of pt is different.
             +------+
```

Comment: Good illustrative explanation.  You might want to clarify why the cast to `(void*)` is required.

Comment: The rationale for the need for a conversion is that on some systems, pointers to different types may have a different representation including a different size and would be passed differently to varadic functions.  For example, Windows used to have near, far and huge pointers.

Comment: Thankyou for such a illustrative explanation.

Answer (score 3):

First, use `%p` to print pointers, not `%d`.

In the beginning of your program, you allocate two variables on the stack: `integer n` (4 bytes) and `int *pt` (4 bytes).

`n` contains integer 3, and `pt` contains the address of `n`. So, `&n` == `pt`.

Then, the third output. Here you print the address of the `pt` variable (which is located on the stack, next to n, see 4 bytes difference).

Answer (score 2):

Not really. In the 3rd number you are printing the address of the pointer itself. The 1st prints the content of the pointer which is the address of n. A pointer is a variable with its own address and is different from the address it is pointing to.

Answer (score -3):

`printf( "%d" )` prints the actual variable value you pass to it.
When you pass pt (a pointer) and print it as a signed integer, than the pointer is "cast" to an integer and `printf()` will yield the memory address as a signed integer. Same goes for pointers to pointers (`&pt`)!
Expect negative numbers, as 50% of the integers are negative!

I'd suggest you to study [this document](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output).

Comment: This has nothing to do with printf requiring variables on the stack.